# Translate jBPMN xml to BPMN Diagram

Tags: jquery, jbpm, bpmn

I have a jBPMN XML file.

Is there a plugin (jQuery) which can convert this XML in to Diagram of BPMN format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking is, I give the jbpm XML and I get the diagram back!

Currently, there are no plugin, tools, software available. JBPM can be used to get the diagram from XML (with a bit of effort)

Answer (score 1):

The jBPM project offers the web-based designer that could be used to do this.  But I assume you're looking for a more lightweight alternative?